# Google Visualization with large data

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

Problem using Google Visualization with large data from JSON.
i have json that return about 5500+ source strings, every string looks like this:

```
{"testRunId":86549,"environment":"DEV","dateExecutes":1504537556000,"passed":7,"failed":0,"skipped":0,"successRate":100.0,"newFailures":0,"analyzed":0,"totalDuration":4686,"averageDuration":669}
```

it works fine when i build charts from about 1000,  but works very slow and stop showing tooltips when it 5000+. please, help solve problem with tooltips, or reduce data source

Comment: @WhiteHat, no, i can't. 
everything works fine, but with less amount of data.

Comment: @WhiteHat, unfortunatly, i have to read data dynamically, and i have read-only acess. Anyway, how can i change the scale of the chart? Like let it draw only first 100 columns for example?